# Google Cloud Storage - files not showing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, leaflet, cloud-hosting

I have over 30 Leaflet maps hosted on my Google Cloud Platform bucket ([for example](https://storage.googleapis.com/leaflet_maps/Agriculture/2015_wheat/templates/index.html)) and it has always been an easy process to upload my folder (which includes an html file with sub-folders including .js and .css files) and share the map publicly.

I tried uploading another map today, but within the folder there are no files showing and I get the following message "There are no live objects in this folder. If you have object versioning enabled, this folder may contain archived versions of objects, which aren't visible in the console. You can list archived object versions using gsutil or the APIs."

Does anyone know what is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have also seen this problem, and it seems that the issue is limited to buckets that have spaces in the name.

It's also not reproducible through the gcloud web console, but if you use gsutil  to upload a file to a bucket with a space in the name then it won't be visible on the web UI.

I can see from your screenshot that your bucket also has spaces (%20 in the url).

If you need a workaround asap, you could rename your bucket...

But google should fix this soon, I hope.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle. I renamed the bucket to have no spaces and this fixed the issue. I hope the bug is fixed soon too!

Answer (score 1):

There is currently open issue on GCS/Console integration
If files have any symbols that needs urlencoding - they are not visible in console - but accessible via gsutil/API (which is currently recommended as workaround)

Issue has been resolved as of 8-May-2018 10:00 UTC

Comment: Thanks, Alexey! I hope they fix this bug soon. In the meantime, I renamed my bucket to have no spaces and it seemed to have done the trick. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the file doesn't have an extension, the UI treats it as a folder and lets you navigate into it, showing a blank folder instead of the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same symptom (files show up in API but invisible on the web and via CLI).

The issue turned out to be that we were saving files to "./uploads", which Google interprets as "create a directory literally called '.' and then a subdirectory called uploads."

The fix was to upload to "uploads/" instead of "./uploads".  We also just ran a mass copy operation via the API for everything under "./uploads".  All visible now!

Answer (score -1):

I also had spaces in my url and it was not working properly yesterday. Checked this morning and everything is working as expected. I still have the spaces in my URL btw.